# Do (special) natural transformations imply a commutative triangle of functors (but NOT vice versa)?

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

Given categories $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}$, let functors $F,G: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be such that

- for any objects $C_1, C_2 \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$, $F(C_1) = F(C_2) \implies G(C_1) = G(C_2)$,
- for any morphisms $f_1, f_2 \in Mor(\mathcal{C})$, $F(f_1) = F(f_2) \implies G(f_1) = G(f_2)$.

In this sense the functors $F$ and $G$ are "special". (The latter condition doesn't follow from the first, correct me if I'm wrong.)

(This condition is necessary to write $G$ "as a function of" $F$, as pointed out in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3108589/606791) to [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104682/can-natural-transformations-be-viewed-as-functors-between-images-of-functors).)

Let $\eta$ be a natural transformation $F \Rightarrow G$, and let $F(\mathcal{C})$ be the [image](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/image#examples)$\dagger$ of $F$, and let $\tilde{F}: \mathcal{C} \to F(\mathcal{C})$ be the functor formed from $F$ by restricting the codomain of $F$ to be $F(\mathcal{C})$.

> **Claim:** The natural transformation induces a functor $H_{\eta}: F(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{D}$ such that $H_{\eta} \circ \tilde{F} = G$, i.e. we have the commutative triangle of functors
> $$\begin{matrix} \mathcal{C} & \overset{\tilde{F}}{\rightarrow} & F(\mathcal{C}) \\
> & \overset{G}{\searrow} & \downarrow H_{\eta} \\ & & \mathcal{D} \end{matrix} $$
> However, $H_{\eta}$ by itself is not enough information to recover the natural transformation $\eta: F \Rightarrow G$. In particular, given an ***arbitrary*** functor $H: F(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{D}$ such that $H \circ \tilde{F} = G$, it could be induced by any other natural transformation $F \Rightarrow G$, or by no natural transformation at all, because such a functor $H$ by itself doesn't specify any choices of morphisms $F(C) \overset{\phi}{\to} G(C)$ for objects $C \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$, just that each $F(C)$ is "associated with" $G(C)$.

**Attempt:** Obviously $H_{\eta}$ has to send each $F(C)$ to $G(C)$ for each $C \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$. Likewise $H_{\eta}$ has to send each $F(f)$ to $G(f)$ for every $f \in Mor(\mathcal{C})$. These two assignments should both be well-defined as a result of the "special" condition required of $F$ and $G$ that was given above.

For any morphisms in $Mor(F(\mathcal{C}))$ that are not of the form $F(f)$ for some $f \in Mor(\mathcal{C})$ (but instead are the composition of such morphisms), to guarantee that $H_{\eta}$ can give a well-defined assignment, it seems to be sufficient to show we can ensure $H_{\eta}$ respects composition of morphisms.

So all that remains is to show that $H_{\eta}$ is a functor by showing it respects composition of morphisms and identities.

That $H_{\eta}$ respects identities follows immediately from $F$ and $G$ being functors, so $F(id_C) = id_{F(C)}$ and $G(id_C) = id_{G(C)}$ for any $C \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$, thus given an identity morphism in $F(\mathcal{C})$, which must be of the form $id_{F(C)}$ for some $C \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$, we have that $H_{\eta} ( id_{F(C)}) = H_{\eta}(F(id_C)) = G(id_C) = id_{G(C)} = id_{H_{\eta}(F(C))}$.

Regarding respecting composition - does this follow from the naturality squares defining $\eta$? Or do we not even need to appeal to that at all, making $H_{\eta}$ in fact completely unrelated to the original natural transformation $\eta$?

**Comment:** Using the identity functor $id_{\mathcal{C}}$ to rewrite the commutative triangle as a commutative square:
$$\begin{matrix} \mathcal{C} & \overset{\tilde{F}}{\rightarrow} & F(\mathcal{C}) \\
id_{\mathcal{C}} \downarrow &  & \downarrow H_{\eta} \\ \mathcal{C} & \overset{G}{\rightarrow} & \mathcal{D} \end{matrix} $$
writing a natural transformation this way as a commutative square of functors seems related to the ideas discussed on [this nLab post](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/natural+transformation+(discussion)). As for the extent to which any of this is really related, I don't know.

$\dagger$ The image $F(\mathcal{C})$ is a category in its own right if we define

- objects $Ob(F(\mathcal{C}))$ as the collection of objects from $Ob(\mathcal{D}$) of the form $F(C)$ for all $C \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$, and
- morphisms $Mor(F(C))$ as the "[transitive closure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transitive+closure)" (under composition) of the collection of morphisms from $Mor(\mathcal{D})$ of the form $F(f)$ for all $f \in Mor(\mathcal{C})$.

In particular, although $F(\mathcal{C})$ so defined will be a [subcategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subcategory) of $\mathcal{D}$ albeit usually not a [full subcategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+subcategory).

Comment: It is very clear with your definition that $H_\eta$ has nothing to do with $\eta$ (though the existence of $\eta$ is in itself a property of $F$ and $G$). It's just a matter of seeing if $H$ preserves composition.

Comment: @CaptainLama That's what I was afraid of. Is it at the very least correct to say that any natural transformation $\eta : F \Rightarrow G$ is "compatible" with any functor $H: F(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{D}$ such that $H \circ \tilde{F} = G$, in the sense that $\eta$ maps the same objects $F(C) \to G(C)$ that $H$ does? (A natural transformation $\eta$ doesn't really imply any _direct_ way to associate morphisms $F(f)$ with $G(f)$, right?)

Comment: In particular, in some sense a natural transformation $\eta: F \Rightarrow G$ is "strictly richer structurally" than a commuting triangle of functors $H \circ \tilde{F} = G$, because the former gives explicit choices of morphisms connecting each $F(C)$ to $G(C)$ for every object $C \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$, whereas the latter, although also sending each $F(C)$ to $G(C)$ for every object in $C \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$, does not "connect" $F(C)$ and $G(C)$ in any way?Yes? This is basically what I am trying to get at in my question. If you want to elaborate on any of this in an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: I guess if $\eta$ is a natural isomorphism, then you even get a direct way to associate morphisms $F(f)$ with $G(f)$, namely via "conjugation", $G(f) = \eta_{C_2} \circ F(f) \circ \eta_{C_1}^{-1}$. And I would guess that this association is still "compatible" with any commutative triangle of functors $H \circ \tilde{F} = G$, while still being "structurally strictly richer" because it gives an explicit formula associating $F(f)$ to $G(f)$, whereas any such functor $H$ just says "$G(f)$ goes with $F(f)$" but in general is completely agnostic about "how". Is that a correct way to think about it?

Comment: Related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080487/can-i-define-a-functor-f-and-a-%ce%94f-of-sorts-which-will-uniquely-determine-a-ne and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308500/basic-category-theory-applying-natural-transformations Those questions sort of ask a "converse" of this one, namely given an $\tilde{F}$ and an $H$ then $H \circ \tilde{F}$ certainly gives a new functor $G$, and then those questions ask whether in that construction the $H$ can be replaced with a natural transformation to get a new functor $G$. Whereas here we want to get $H$ from $G$ and $F$.